# Transcoding video 1080p to 720p while preserving aspect ratio with padding on Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I need to transcode a video file on Android from an arbitrary aspect ratio, such as 1920x1080 to 720p, while preserving the original aspect ratio, adding padding, if necessary.

I am using [this CTS file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java) as a reference.

I tried adding

```
outputVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO_WIDTH, 720);
outputVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO_HEIGHT, 1280);
```

and also

```
codec.setVideoScalingMode(VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

to every callback method belonging to both encoder and decoder, i.e. `onOutputFormatChanged()`, `onInputBufferAvailable()`, `onOutputBufferAvailable()`.

Also, I added the call to `decoder.setVideoScalingMode()` and `encoder.setVideoScalingMode()` right before creation of both encoder and decoder, as suggested [here](https://programtalk.com/java-more-examples/android.media.MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING/).

Unfortunately, none of the approaches above helped preserve the original aspect ratio.

Is there any other way to do it on Android I may be missing?

p.s.: yes, I know I am trying to use a cropping option to implement preserved padded aspect ratio, but this is the closest option I was able to find.

Answer (score 0):

As someone here previously suggested and then deleted their answer, I will be using [Mp4Composer](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/) as a reference.